# Uglifyjs node js

Tags: node.js

This is the code written by me to get all the js files in a directory to be minified:

```
var http = require('http');

var  testFolder = './tests/';
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var fs = require('fs');
var glob = require("glob");
var fillnam="";
hello();
function hello()
{
  glob("gen/*.js", function (er, files) {
    //console.log(files);
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
      fillnam=files[i];
      console.log("File Name "+fillnam);
      fs.readFile(fillnam, 'utf8', function (err,data)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(fillnam+" "+data);
        var result = UglifyJS.minify(data);
        var gtemp_file=fillnam.replace(".js","");
        console.log(gtemp_file);
        fs.writeFile(gtemp_file+".min.js", result.code, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("File was successfully saved.");
            }
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

As a result respective minified js files with same name with `.min.js` should be formed in the same directory.

But what I am getting is a single file with all files data over written. Like for example if there are two files in a directory `a.js` and `b.js` with content:

```
 var a=10;var b=20;
 var name="stack";
```

What I'm getting is single file `a.min.js` with file content:

```
var a=10tack;
```

Please help.

Comment: You want 'fillnam' to be inside the scope of the for loop, I'm guessing it's getting confused since readFile and writeFile are asynchronous.

Comment: you mean asynchronous :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect all file contents first, concat them and then run `UglifyJS.minify` on them to be able to save it as a single file.

Something like this (not fully tested)

```js
const testFolder = './tests/';
const UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile);
const glob = require("glob");

function hello() {
  glob("gen/*.js", async(er, files) {
    let data = [];
    for (const file of files) {
      const fileData = await readFile(file, {
        encoding: 'utf-8'
      });
      data.push(fileData);
    }

    const uglified = UglifyJS.minify(data.join('\n'));
    fs.writeFile('main.min.js', uglified);
  });
}

hello();
```

Comment: I dont want to put all in one file ! I want 1 min file for 1 js ! How to do that !